# Getting undefined index while fetching column value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code :

```
$sql = 'select count(*) from match as count where match_status != :status';
      $query = $con->prepare($sql);
      $query->bindValue(':status',LOST,PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $query->execute();
      $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if(!empty($row))
        $row_count = $row['count'];
      else
        $row_count = 0;
```

I am getting `Notice: Undefined index: count`

What's the mistake?

Comment: For one thing, you're using the MySQL reserved word `match`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html - Having used error checking and exceptions, would have thrown you an error. `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: Plus, it's more than likely that you're using MySQL and not MSSQL, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You created the alias for the wrong thing. This should work:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM `match` WHERE match_status != :status
                 //^^^^^ Alias for 'count(*)' NOT for your table name
```

Also you have to put ` around keywords/Mysql reserved words e.g. `match`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

And if you turn on error mode then you also get an error for this, just put it right after your connection:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: I think the downvote is one done in spite. It needs to be retracted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'select count(*) from match as count where match_status != :status';
```

In this query, the `as count` won't do a thing, because you don't know what column you want to rename.
You need to place it directly after the original column name, so the database knows what column-name it needs to hide:

```
$sql = 'select count(*) as count from `match` where `match_status` != :status';
```

Because of this `$row['count']` won't work, because you don't have a count-column, only a count(*) column.

**N.B.:** You're using a MySQL reserved word, being `match` and requires special attention in MySQL. Either rename it to something else, or use ticks around it, in order to escape it properly.

Comment: There's an important thing you forgot about the table name.

Comment: Yes, and no. Table names (and column names) should be escaped, but... 2 things: How do we know what kind of escaping it needs? (Ok, I just saw the MySQL tag, so we do know, but it could be MSSQL which is using another kind of escaping). And in this case it's not needed. Only when you are using tables with a fulltext index you cannot use this name (without escaping).

Comment: They tagged the question as `mysql`. Therefore the table name needs to be given special atttention. Even the MSSQL documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx says to avoid using them.

Comment: We're all in this to learn and to let others know where the errors were made; it's not a competition. As it stands, your answer doesn't fully remedy the OP's problem and should also benefit future readers to the question. The issue is (still) with the table name. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html